# Calculating Distance iOS MapKit Using CLLocation

Tags: ios, mapkit

I am trying to find the distance in miles using the latitude and longitude. I have the following method:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
    didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation
           fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
    if(!newLocation) return; 

    if ((oldLocation.coordinate.latitude != newLocation.coordinate.latitude) &&
        (oldLocation.coordinate.longitude != newLocation.coordinate.longitude))
    {



        CLLocation *loc1 = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:oldLocation.coordinate.latitude longitude:oldLocation.coordinate.longitude];
        CLLocation *loc2 = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:newLocation.coordinate.latitude longitude:newLocation.coordinate.latitude];

        CLLocationDistance distance = ([loc2 distanceFromLocation:loc1]) * 0.000621371192;

        //distance = distance; 

        NSLog(@"Total Distance %f in miles",distance);
    }

}
```

For some reason it prints out something like 5678.32 miles. The location is pretty much stationary and not moving at all.

Comment: Just interested, why do you multiply by 0.000621371192 ?

Comment: CLLocation *loc2 = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:newLocation.coordinate.(!!!!!)latitude longitude:newLocation.coordinate.(!!!!!)latitude];

Comment: There are 1,609.344 metres in a mile, and 1/1609.344 is 0.000621371192237.

Comment: @Alexander: you should probably post that as an answer.

Comment: HAHAH got it! THanks duh. @Alexander can you please post that as an answer so I can accept!

Comment: @Tommy. That's not an answer. To begin with this is not a question. :)

Comment: Why are the (!!!!!) there? What are those for?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
CLLocation *loc2 = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:newLocation.coordinate.(!!!!!)latitude longitude:newLocation.coordinate.(!!!!!)latitude];
```

Comment: @IanDundas the position to look at to see an error :)

Answer (score 3):

You are initializing loc2 with the latitude of the new location for both the longitude and the latitude:

This line:

```
CLLocation *loc2 = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:newLocation.coordinate.latitude longitude:newLocation.coordinate.latitude];
```

Should say:

```
CLLocation *loc2 = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:newLocation.coordinate.latitude longitude:newLocation.coordinate.longitude];
```

Hope it helps!