# iPhone App: Calculate Distance of path in Google maps

Tags: iphone, objective-c, google-maps, mapkit

I am developing an iPhone app. here in my App I have included Google maps.I am showing the highlighted  path in map.

Now my Question is how to calculate distance  between two point as per path as Apple"s native map App is showing routes with distance.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calculating Distance iOS MapKit Using CLLocation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6685553/calculating-distance-ios-mapkit-using-cllocation)

Answer (score 0):

```
    CLLocation *loc1 = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:oldLocation.coordinate.latitude longitude:oldLocation.coordinate.longitude];
    CLLocation *loc2 = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:newLocation.coordinate.latitude longitude:newLocation.coordinate.latitude];

    CLLocationDistance distance = ([loc2 distanceFromLocation:loc1]) * 0.000621371192;
```

Comment: Thanks for replay but will it give me relative distance between two point as per route.

Comment: No, you can't get routes from MapKit (as you have your question tagged)

Answer (score 0):

This may help you.

When running in the simulator, Core Location assigns a fixed set of coordinate values to this property. You must run your application on an iOS-based device to get real location values.

```
CLLocation *loc2 = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:newLocation.coordinate.latitude longitude:newLocation.coordinate.latitude];
```

Comment: more help in this link http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocation_Class/CLLocation/CLLocation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007126